# Excel VBA hide 3000 rows optimizing

Tags: performance, vba, excel, for-loop

My first question :)

Have a sheet with 3000 lines that needs to be checked and hided every time the sheet is activated.

Normally only 100 lines are to be visible but I had to make sure it always was enough lines. (Just in case).

I have this code that works well but are a little slow. Tips for speeding it up would be great.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
On Error GoTo ExitHandling

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

        'Hide Operations columns if no values
        If Worksheets("BasicData").Range("CheckOperationsZero").Value = "Yes" Then
            Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If

        'Hide empty rows, dont hide if row belowe is not empty, autofit for better viewing
        ActiveSheet.Rows("17:3017").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        For I = 3016 To 18 Step -1
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B" & I & ":J" & I), vbNullString) >= 9 And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("B" & I + 1 & ":J" & I + 1), vbNullString) >= 9 Then
                Rows(I).RowHeight = 12
                Rows(I).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Else
                Rows(I).EntireRow.AutoFit
                    If Rows(I).Height < 20 Then
                        Rows(I).RowHeight = 12
                    End If
            End If
        Next I

ExitHandling:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandling

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just find the number of rows and then hide them?

Comment: Why loop? Do them all at once.  `ActiveSheet.Rows("17:3017").EntireRow.Hidden = True` and `Rows("17:3017").RowHeight = 12`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code uses 2 optimisations:
- calculate each row's state only once, not twice, by saving the previously computed value for the next iteration
- collect all empty rows in one range object and format this in one step. Format the rest of the range by addressing the "visible" cells (via SpecialCells).

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ' optimized for performance
    Const entireRange = "B17:J3017"

    Dim rowptr As Range
    Dim emptyrows As Range
    Dim I As Long
    Dim thisRowIsEmpty As Boolean, nextRowIsEmpty As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ExitHandling

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Hide Operations columns if no values
    If Worksheets("BasicData").Range("CheckOperationsZero").Value = "Yes" Then
        Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Else
        Columns("I:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If

    'Hide empty rows, dont hide if row belowe is not empty, autofit for better viewing
    Rows("17:3017").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Set emptyrows = Cells(5000, 1)
    Set rowptr = Range("B3017:J3017")
    nextRowIsEmpty = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rowptr, vbNullString) >= 9
    For I = 3016 To 18 Step -1
        Set rowptr = rowptr.Offset(-1, 0)
        thisRowIsEmpty = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rowptr, vbNullString) >= 9
        If thisRowIsEmpty And nextRowIsEmpty Then
            Set emptyrows = Application.Union(emptyrows, rowptr)
        End If
        nextRowIsEmpty = thisRowIsEmpty
    Next I

    If Not emptyrows Is Nothing Then
        With emptyrows
            .RowHeight = 12
            .EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End With
    End If
    With Range(entireRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        .AutoFit
        If .Height < 20 Then
            .RowHeight = 12
        End If
    End With

ExitHandling:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandling:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume ExitHandling
End Sub
```

On my notebook this code will run in 0.15 s instead of 2.0 s, so the speedup is roughly 10:1.

Comment: That made a huge difference. Perfect score inn all ways :) Thanx for taking the time. Only fault i found was this part:

Comment: With Range(entireRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        .AutoFit
        If .Height < 20 Then
            .RowHeight = 12
        End If
    End With

Comment: The ide was to autofit to detect if some rows needed to be more than 12 in height. And rest of the rows i wanted to be 12 in height...

Comment: I thought I had included that part exactly as it was. Should I correct something?

Comment: The problem im looking to solve is that is when im setting the height to 12 on all visible rows the rows that need text wrapping also get 12 in height. The reason for not using autofit on all is that it makes unnecessary heigh rows. Previosly my solution was to autofit all, then loop thru and check height, the rows that was less than 20 hight i knew was only one line, and could set to 12 height. Rows with height greather than 20 i knew was 2 lines or more and could just leave as autofitet. Hope that explained what that code mentioned in prevoisly comment was about.

Comment: `code`    With Range(entireRange).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
        .AutoFit
    End With
    
    For I = 3019 To 20 Step -1
        If Rows(I).Height < 16 And Rows(I).Hidden = False Then
            Rows(I).RowHeight = 13
        End If
        If Rows(I).Height > 16 And Rows(I).Hidden = False Then
            Rows(I).RowHeight = Rows(I).Height + 2
        End If
    Next I

Answer (score -1):

Here's an old post of mine. [How to speed up multiple replacement using VBA in Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071366/how-to-speed-up-multiple-replacement-using-vba-in-word)

Remember MINIMISE DOTS.

Read the post as it lists 4 performance killers.

> **Minimise Dots**
>
> So if you are interested in performance minimise dots (each dot is a lookup), especially in loops.
>
> There are two ways. One is to set objects to the lowest object if you are going to access more than once.
>
> eg (slower)
>
> `set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
>
> `msgbox xlapp.worksheets(0).name`
>
> (faster because you omitt a dot every time you use the object)
>
> `set xlapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")`
>
> `set wsheet = xlapp.worksheets(0)`
>
> `msgbox wsheet.name`
>
> The second way is `with`. You can only have one `with` active at a time.
>
> This skips 100 lookups.
>
> `with wsheet`
>
> `For x = 1 to 100`
>
> ```
>     `msgbox .name`
> ```
>
> `Next`
>
> `end with`