# Delete blank cells in a column

Tags: excel, vba

The following code converts a table of values to a single column.

The problem is, with my table the number of rows in each column decreases by one for each successive column. Similar to the table shown below.

I am VERY new to writing code and only know the very basics.  I copied a script found online to convert a range of values to a single column. The portion of code that I wrote to delete any blank cells is slowing the code tremendously.  To convert around 250,000 points to a column is taking roughly 9 hours.  I am hoping to reduce the processing time as this is a script I expect to use regularly.

```
Sub CombineColumns()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim rng As Range
Dim iCol As Long
Dim lastCell As Long
Dim K As Long

K = 484
'set K equal to the number of data points that created the range


Set rng = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion
lastCell = rng.Columns(1).Rows.count + 1

For iCol = 2 To rng.Columns.count
    Range(Cells(1, iCol), Cells(rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.count, iCol)).Cut
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Cells(lastCell, 1)
    lastCell = lastCell + rng.Columns(iCol).Rows.count

Next iCol
Dim z As Long
Dim m As Long

z = K ^ 2

For Row = z To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(Row, 1) = 0 Then
    Range("A" & Row).Delete Shift:=xlUp

    Application.StatusBar = "Progress: " & Row & " of z: " & Format((z - Row) / z, "Percent")
    DoEvents

    End If

Next

Application.StatusBar = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Sample Table Structure
[image: Sample Table Structure]

Comment: 1. this is a better question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com 2. When you do, **DO NOT** post picture of your code and example data.  Paste the code and data directly in the post then highlight them and hit Ctrl-k to format it.

Comment: Please post the code directly here. It would then be possible for me to run it. You can try to put a msgbox between the two parts and see if the second part is slower than the first part. Which I assume is true, because you delete rows and Excel then needs to shift lots of cells.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ScottCraner -  Judging by the screenshot, this isn't working code. The row delete loop is running backwards (or in the wrong direction depending on your point of view).

Comment: @Comintern to be honest I went by his description that the code was working, I did not do more than a cursory view of the code.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I sometimes get sucked in by the novelty of code screenshots.

Comment: Does it always decrease by 1 cell each column to the right

Comment: @ScottCraner My apologies on the poor posting etiquette.  This is my first post here, in the future I will format the code so it can be copied and go the site mentions by for code reviews.

Comment: @zanwigz fix it here.  Do not post it on CodeReview as they will see it as not working.  See my answer below.

Comment: @StevenMartin yes there is always a decrease by one cell to the right.

Comment: @keiv.fly I just editted to include the code.@Comintern I changed the loop to run the other way with the Step-1.  I am running it now, however, it still seems slow (around 8 percent done after 10 min).  If it works I'll hop over to codereview to get some imput on improving the speed.

Comment: See my answer here on speeding up VBA from a language viewpoint - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071366/how-to-speed-up-multiple-replacement-using-vba-in-word/26080089#26080089. It includes a link at the bottom to a page on Excel specific speeding up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Because I gave errant information on where this should be posted.

The following code will do what you want nearly instantly.

I used arrays to limit the number of interactions with the worksheet.

```
Sub foo5()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng() As Variant
Dim oarr() As Variant
Dim i&, j&, k&


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet19") 'Change to your sheet
With ws
    rng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))).Value
    ReDim oarr(1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng), 1 To 1)
    k = 1
    For i = LBound(rng, 1) To UBound(rng, 1)
        For j = LBound(rng, 2) To UBound(rng, 2)
            If rng(i, j) <> "" Then
                oarr(k, 1) = rng(i, j)
                k = k + 1
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
    .Range("A1", .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))).Clear
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(oarr), 1).Value = oarr
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: working code compared to non working code is definitely an improvement in efficiency!

Comment: @Scott Craner I just tried to run this.  While the code ran successively, after row 5304 the columns were assigned a value of N/A, whereas I should have around 117000 entries.

Comment: @ForwardEd Yes I Agree!!

Comment: @zanwigz did the edit work for you?  I just tried it on a 484 x 484 grid and it was less than a second.  If it worked please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Comment: @ScottCraner I am afraid it is still not working for me.  Now, it will move the second column down below the first, then the code ends.

Comment: What is the actual range of your dataset? @zanwigz

Comment: @ScottCraner The data range is from A1 to RO483.  With 482 rows in column 1, 481 rows in column 2 ect.. stepping down until only one row of data is in the last column (RO or Column 483).

Comment: @ScottCranerApologies!  Editted

Comment: Like I stated in the comment earlier.  I tested it with a grid just like the one described.  At this point I cannot offer any more direction without seeing the actual data.  I had no problems and cannot replicate your issue.