# Changing style of words, depending on whether the word is bold or not, is slow

Tags: vba, ms-word

I´d like to change the style of several words within the active document.

- Each word could appear more than once.
- Some words are bold and some are unbold.

The words are stored in array `Arr()`.

If the word X found is unbold, replace the style to `StyleA` and if it is bold change it to `StyleB`.

The following code has two issues.

1) Words with bold and not bold format change to `StyleA`.
2) The execution time is slow. I tested the loop from 1 to 5 and it took almost a minute.

```
Sub ReplaceStyle()
    Dim Arr(1 to 200)

    Arr(1) = "Word1"
    Arr(2) = "Word2"
    .
    .
    .
    Arr(200) = "Word200"

    For i = 1 To Ubound(Arr)
        With Selection.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = Arr(i)
            .Replacement.Text = ""

            If Selection.Font.Bold = False Then
                .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleA")
            Else
                .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleB")
            End If

            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = True
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071366/how-to-speed-up-multiple-replacement-using-vba-in-word/26080089#26080089

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the code in the question is faulty. `Find` needs to have actually *located* the search term before code can test whether it's bold or not bold.

Two basic approaches would be possible

1. Search the term, when found perform the test and apply the style
2. Search each term twice, once for bold and once for not bold

You'd need to test, but based on experience I believe the second approach would be faster as it can use `ReplaceAll`.

The code below demonstrates the principle, based on the code in the question. Note that it uses a `Range` object, rather than `Selection` as this is generally more efficient.

```
Sub FindReplaceFormattingVariations()
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    Dim searchTerm As String
    Dim Arr(1 to 200)

    Arr(1) = "Word1"
    Arr(2) = "Word2"
    .
    .
    .
    Arr(200) = "Word200"

For i = 1 To Ubound(Arr) 
    searchTerm = Arr(i)
    Set rng = ActiveDocument.content
    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = searchTerm
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleA")
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

    With rng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = searchTerm
        .Font.Bold = False
        .Replacement.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("StyleB")
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next    
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Cindy. Thanks again for your help. The code it seems to work regarding changing the style, but it changes to whole paragraph where the word if found, not only the word itself. Other thing is if the word is followed for example by a comma, the style is not changed. The speed issue it seems to be something about MS Word itself.

Comment: @GerCas You did not specify *what kind* of style is to be applied. My assumption was a character style, as it should be applied to single words. If this the style is a *paragraph* style, it will, logically, affect the entire paragraph. Create a character style for this use, then test again. And make sure your `Find` properties do not specify to match the whole word.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Forgive my low knowledge about this. I only created a style and thought would be applied to single matched word. I just cannot find the option to set the style to work only for matched word and disallow the style to whole paragraph.

Comment: @gercas But you're alright, now? You found the option to set the style type?

Comment: Actually I didn't find the option to tell the style to work at word level only, not paragraph level. I did click on styles and then create style, but I don't see option related to paragraphs.

Comment: I'm currently on a mobile device, so can't give you the exact menu names but... In the New Style (or Modify) dialog box, in the top line you enter the style name. In one of the next lines you specify the style type. That's a dropdown with, as I recall, three entries, paragraph being the default. The other two are character and linked. The two lines below that set the style to follow and the style to base the new one one (just to give you some orientation - you shouldn't need to set these).

Comment: I found it. I set it to style type= character. I'll try again. Thanks so much for your kindness.