# speed up Excel vba program

Tags: excel, vba

Kindly see below code where it takes too much time run for more than 30rows in a range. (its similar to knapsack algorithm requirements)

let me try to explain below in detail,
Input Base sheet: Column A having values (For ex: 1555),
Column B having its Assignment value (A1),
Column C & D its filter value which will perform against input data sheet file.

Program working concept:
it takes first row(2) data from base sheet and apply filter (C2 & D2 value) in input data sheet (Column A & B respectively) then it checks value in column C and it find best sum to match the value (1555) or nearest to it and after it assigns value (which is A1) against those rows and repeats the same for next rows.

I have posted image below.
Kindly refer for Input Base sheet and Input Data sheet and
copy the codes in another workbook.
Run the macro, Choose Base sheet and the Data sheet. Program would run and assigns in Input data sheet. It runs super fast in lesser rows when I have more rows it gets hang/takes too hours to run.

Help me to where it can be speed up.

Appreciate your supports.

Thanks

input base sheet

[image: base sheet]

input data sheet:

[image: datas sheet]

```
Sub sample1()

Dim lrow As Integer
Dim frow As Integer
Dim row As Integer
Dim ar As Variant
Dim aar As Variant
Dim Sol(), csol()
Dim arr As Variant
Dim pos As Integer
Dim arow() As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rn As Range
Dim r As Range
Dim k As Integer
Dim itr As Integer
Dim path As String

Dim tm_base As Workbook
Dim tm_data As Workbook
Dim sh_base As Worksheet
Dim sh_data As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set sh = ActiveSheet

ReDim arr(0)
arr(0) = ""
path = FileSelection("Input Base")
If path = "" Then Exit Sub
Set tm_base = Workbooks.Open(path)
path = FileSelection("Input Data")
If path = "" Then Exit Sub
Set tm_data = Workbooks.Open(path)

Set sh_base = tm_base.ActiveSheet
Set sh_data = tm_data.ActiveSheet

lrow = sh_data.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
frow = sh_base.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

SortMacro ActiveSheet, sh_base.Range("A2:A" & frow), sh_base.Range("A1:G" & frow), 2
SortMacro ActiveSheet, sh_data.Range("C2:C" & lrow), sh_data.Range("A1:G" & lrow), 2

For row = 2 To frow
    
    If sh_base.Cells(row, "H") <> "Done" Then
    
        itr = 1
        sh_data.Range("A1:G" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="="
op2:
        sh_data.Range("A1:G" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=sh_base.Cells(row, "C").Value
        sh_data.Range("A1:G" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=sh_base.Cells(row, "D").Value
        
        
        Set rn = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rn = sh_data.Range("C2:C" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rn Is Nothing Then
            ReDim ar(0)
            ReDim arow(0)
            k = 1
            For Each r In rn
                ReDim Preserve arow(k)
                ReDim Preserve ar(k)
                ar(k) = r.Value
                arow(k) = r.row
                k = k + 1
            Next
        
            ReDim Sol(LBound(ar) To UBound(ar))
            ReDim csol(LBound(ar) To UBound(ar))
            
            limsum = sh_base.Cells(row, "A").Value
            
            For i = LBound(ar) To UBound(ar)
                If ar(i) > limsum Then
                    ar(i) = -1
                End If
            Next
            
            maxsum = 0
            
            findsum ar, Sol, csol, maxsum, limsum, UBound(ar), UBound(ar)
            ss = ""
            For i = 1 To Sol(0)
                'ss = ss & sep & ar(sol(i))
                'sep = ","
                If Not arr(UBound(arr)) = "" Then
                    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)
                End If
        
                arr(UBound(arr)) = ar(Sol(i))
            Next i
            'MsgBox ss & " sum =" & maxsum
            
            For j = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                pos = Application.Match(arr(j), ar, False)
                
                If ar(pos - 1) > 0 Then
                    ar(pos - 1) = -1
                End If
                pos = arow(pos - 1)
                If sh.Range("B1") = "Option 01" Then
                    sh_data.Cells(pos, "D") = sh_base.Cells(row, "B").Value
                Else
                    sh_data.Cells(pos, "D") = sh_base.Cells(row, "B").Value & " " & Format(itr, "00")
                End If
                
            Next
            ReDim arr(0)
            arr(0) = ""
            sh_base.Cells(row, "H") = "Done"
            
            If sh.Range("B1") = "Option 02" Then
                sh_data.Range("A1:G" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="="
                Set rng = sh_data.Range("A1:A" & lrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
                    itr = itr + 1
                    GoTo op2
                End If
            End If
        
        End If
               
        sh_data.Range("A1:G" & frow).AutoFilter Field:=1
        sh_data.Range("A1:G" & frow).AutoFilter Field:=2
        sh_data.Range("A1:G" & lrow).AutoFilter Field:=4
    End If
Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

```
Sub findsum(ByVal a, ByRef Sol, ByRef csol, ByRef maxsum, ByRef limsum, si, maxcount, Optional s = 0, Optional lvl = 1, Optional dif = 100000, Optional minuscount = 0, Optional tsol, Optional j = 0)
' recursive sub
    For i = LBound(a) To si
        If a(i) > 0 Then
            If s + a(i) > limsum Then findsum a, Sol, csol, maxsum, limsum, i - 1, maxcount, s, lvl + 1, dif, minuscount, tsol
            s = s + a(i)
            csol(lvl) = i    
            If s <= limsum Then
                If s > maxsum Then    ' we found a sum greater than current max we save it
                    maxsum = s
                    Sol(0) = lvl
                    For j = 1 To lvl
                        Sol(j) = csol(j)
                    Next j
                End If
                If i > LBound(a) Then    ' pick another number
                    findsum a, Sol, csol, maxsum, limsum, i - 1, maxcount, s, lvl + 1, dif, minuscount, tsol
                End If
            End If
            s = s - a(i)
            If maxsum = limsum Then Exit For 'exit if exact match
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

```
Sub SortMacro(ws As Worksheet, rn As Range, rng As Range, ord As Integer)
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=rn, _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=ord, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange rng
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Function FileSelection(file As String)
Dim path    As String
Dim st      As String

Dim i       As Integer
Dim j       As Integer

FileSelection = ""

With Application.FileDialog(3)
    .title = "Select the " & file & " file"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = st
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "You didn't select the file!", vbExclamation, "Canceled"
        Exit Function
    Else
        FileSelection = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I read your `dims` and stopped reading. `Integers` were really good in the 1980s. CPU designers optimised 16 bit numbers. Later they optimised 32 bit numbers. Now they optimise 32 and 64 bit numbers (as most non pointers are 32 bit).

Comment: @Lundt what you're suggesting? I could not get it

Comment: Integers are 16 bit in VBA. This is because VBA uses 16 bit Windows and CPUs terminology. In 32 bit Windows an Integer is 32 bit (in CPU terms) but called a `long` in VBA. This is because 32bit VBA was designed to import 16 bit VBA with almost no changes. Also 64bit VBA also uses 16bit terminology. So modern CPUs want integers (called a long in VBA) or 64bit unsigned integers (as 64bit CPUs are both 32 and 64 bit CPUs). Also see my answer here and note the last link my answer that addresses other issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26071366/speed-up-multiple-replacement

Comment: @Lundt Understood, I have modified dims and recommendations mentioned in above link. slightly improved but still taking longer time for 200rows. Can you go through full code and suggest me where all I can modify to speed up please? I'm very beginner though in excel vba. Thanks for your reply

Comment: This won't make you code run faster, but you exit the first Sub with Calculation set as xlCalculationManual. Strongly recommend you set it to xlCalculationAutomatic, unless you know really know what you are doing and it is intentional. Anyway, move your Exit Sub code to before Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual or change Exit Sub to a Goto statment that goes to a Label just  before Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic.

Comment: Your code is not commented. It needs to be commented for others to understand it (and for you to understand it in 5 years time). Related you must show your data, and if repetitive, a sample of it. And that data must appear in your comments. And comments state what you are trying to do. PS The Queen is dead, long live the King.

Comment: I have added related input sheets for better understanding @Lundt

Comment: @Andrew I did that but still its super slow

Comment: @Lundt It makes slower the program when filter results more than 30rows data.

Comment: Adam, my recommendation won't do anything to help with the speed. It just creates a safer enviroment. Saving files with Excel set to Manual Calcuation can lead to big problems for the unwary. Any files saved with Excel set to Manual Calcuation means that Excel is set that way the next time if it's the first file you open. And all other files opened thereafter will be saved that way too. It will also happen to other people who open your files if they are the first files opened.

Comment: You need to explain it in english what the purpose is. None of us have your spreadsheet. So none of us can run your code in a debugger, the normal way you fix code.

Comment: Oh sorry @Lundt, let me try to explain below in detail,

Input Base sheet: 
Column A having values (For ex: 1345), Column B having its Assignment value (A1), Column C & D its filter value which will perform against next input data sheet.

Program working concept:
it takes first row(2) data and apply filter (C2 & D2 value) in input data sheet  (Column A & B respectively) then it checks value in column C and it find best to match the value (1345) or nearest to it and after it assigns value (which is A1) against those rows and repeats the same.

Comment: I have posted image in main content. Kindly refer for Input Base sheet and Input Data sheet and copy the codes in another workbook.

Run the macro, 
Choose Base sheet and the Data sheet. 
Program would run and assigns in Input data sheet.

It runs super fast in lesser rows when I have more rows it gets hang.

Comment: I see two opportunities: 1) while you already have many array operations (that's good) there remains several direct range references in (nested) for loops.  Convert those to array operations too. 2) you have several Redim Preserve 's inside loops. Those are time expensive. Either calculate the array size before the loop and Redim to that once, or if you can't do that, Redim to an oversize before the loop, and Redim Preserve  to the final size after the loop, once

Comment: @chrisneilsen Thanks
Can you help me to update the code and provide pls?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. I ran it. With 20 base data points and 100 data points you already have sub findsum called 79 million times. It's a combinatorial explosion and no amount of code tweaking will fix that. You'll have to find a better algorithm.